# PC won't display anything on the monitor

Tags: graphics-card, display

I have a problem with my PC. When I press the button to turn it on, it's working but it won't show anything on the monitor!

I think there might a problem with the graphic card or something. What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If everything used to work, then a graphics card failure is rather low on the list of things that can can go wrong.  Things to check first (and maybe double check):

1. Monitor's AC cord is plugged in on both ends.
2. Video cable (VGA, DVI or HDMI?) is plugged in on both ends.
3. Substitute a different monitor.
4. Substitute a different video cable.

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible reasons:

- The monitor cables are not properly connected.
- The monitor is not plugged in or turned on.
- If there is more than one GPU (such as onboard and discrete GPUs), the monitor is connected to the wrong GPU.
- The video cables or connectors, on the monitor or graphics card, are damaged.
- The graphics card is not properly seated in its expansion slot.
- There is not enough power from the power supply reaching the graphics card, or the power supply is failing.
- The monitor is broken.
- The graphics card is broken (the BIOS may detect this problem and give a beep code).

Comment: The BIOS cannot detect all instances where the graphics card could be broken.